# How to wrap jquery animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wrap centralize calling jQuery .animate n my app

```
    $('#' + this.elmItem).animate({"top": moveTo}, speed, function() {
        var item = scope.getItemSizeDom();
        scope.saveItemSize(item);
    }); // This works
```

I am trying to wrap in a method with no success, could you tell me what I am doing wrong here an example of how to fix it?

```
this.itemAnimate = function(direction, moveTo, speed) {
    $('#' + this.elmItem).animate({direction: moveTo}, speed, function() {
        var item = scope.getItemSizeDom();
        scope.saveItemSize(item);
    });// This does not work
};

this.itemAnimate("top", moveTo, "fast");
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: What is `this`, and why would itemAnimate be chainable, it's just a function ?

Comment: sorry... method item animate it is in a class

Comment: There are no classes, is it prototyped or in a literal or ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass object as parameter to animate method:

```
this.itemAnimate = function (direction, moveTo, speed) {
    var param = {};
    param[direction] = moveTo;
    $('#' + this.elmItem).animate(param, speed, function () {
        var item = scope.getItemSizeDom();
        scope.saveItemSize(item);
    }); // This does not work
};
```

Comment: Using object literal notation you can define a property key of object using a variable string. I don't know if it is your question here. This code gives an object: `{top: moveTo}` where moveTo is the value passed as param

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a basic jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.itemAnimate = function(direction, moveTo, speed) {
    var params = {};
    params[direction] = moveTo;
    $(this).animate(params, speed, function() {
         //do something here
    });
};
```

And then call it:

```
$("whatever").itemAnimate("top", moveTo, "fast");
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/yJ6es/)

Answer (score 0):

Some reading: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

The function does not know what `this` is because it does not have context. Give it context like this:

```
this.itemAnimate.apply(this, ["top", moveTo, "fast"]);
```

rather than

```
this.itemAnimate("top", moveTo, "fast");
```

But it would be better if you aliased `this` to some other variable so it does not get lost in the scope chain.

```
var my_thing = this; // be descriptive about what it is exactly.
my_thing.itemAnimate.apply(my_thing, ["top", moveTo, "fast"]);
```